# Enable CDN to S3 bucket without granting public access in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to set up Amazon cloud front with s3 bucket behind. As per my company policy i cannot grant public access to the bucket.

How can we achieve this without violating company security?

People should able to access content with only URL.

Comment: Use cloudfront.

Comment: Did you try the steps in their recommended page? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-access-to-amazon-s3/

Comment: If you need to share objects on an object-by-object basis, then you can generate and share pre-signed URLs. If you want to use 'normal' HTTP web access to an object, but not make the bucket public, then you should use CloudFront (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-task-list.html). Your bucket policy would allow access from the CloudFront OIA associated with your CF distribution. You can also used signed URLs with CloudFront. Are you using CloudFront? What is not working for you?